# Clarifying introductory canonical ensamble reasoning

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I attach a picture of the notes I am using in statistical mechanics , this is the introduction to the canonical ensemble. What I don't understand is the part highlighted in yellow, that is:

**"Since we do expect that only values around $\tilde E_1$ to be
relevant, and considering that $\tilde E_1 << E$ , we can expand $Ω_2$ around $E$, or better, its logarithm, around $E_1 = 0$"**

I don't get the reasoning  here, why do they choose to expand around $E_1 = 0$ . Wouldn't it make more sense to expand around $E_1$ if I see it as a perturbation of $E$, why do they set it equal to 0?

and why does the decision to expand follow from the fact that only values around $\tilde E_1$ are relevant?, they are not even using $\tilde E_1$ in the expansion

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There must be  typos. It should surely read "since we expect only values around $E$ to be relevent, and since $E_1\ll E$ we can expand $\Omega$ around $E$, or better its logarithm around $E$".

Comment: But the expansion seems to be around $E1=0$, I mean the first term $S_2(E)$ is$ S_2(E-E_1) $evaluated at$ E_1=0$, the second term has as coefficient the derivative of $S_2$ with respect to$ E_1$ (which is $1/T$) evauated at $E_1=0$, but $E_1$ doesn't show anymore so it's just $1/T$

Comment: $\tilde E_1$ had been used before to denote the point at which the entropy attains its maximum value in the interval $E-\delta E , E$ and to state that in that interval only that value matters, because is the one that maximizes the probability

Comment: The derivatives of $S_2$ are taken at $E$, so one is expanding about $E$ in powers of $E_1$.

Comment: I guess that is actually the typo, actually in my lecture the professor wrote derivative with respect to $E_1$ in that line. E is a constant, the total energy of the two subsystems, and $S_2$ is a  function of its energy or implicitly a function of $E_1$  : $E_2 = E-E_1$